# Does the Thinkpad X41 Touchscreen work with Ubuntu?

Tags: laptop, configuration, compatibility, touchscreen

I was just wondering if laptop touch screens, such as the one on the ThinkPad X41 were compatible with Ubuntu. I have my new stylus coming in the mail, so I can't see for myself yet.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using the x41 with stylus for years and stylus worked out of the box with almost any ubuntu release. Particular settings are possible with Inkscape and Gimp. Mypaint is nice to use, too. Enjoy.